# What is the difference between a Struct and an Enum in Rust

Tags: rust, struct, enums, rust-cargo

Coming from javascript/python I'm used to the idea of classes but am struggling to understand the difference between a Struct and an Enum.

For example I can define a 'class' with behaviours in similar ways

struct

```
// Defines the StartListen class
pub struct StartListen {
    socket: SocketAddr,
    listener: TcpListener,
}

// Implementation for StartListen class
impl StartListen {
    pub async fn new(socket: SocketAddr) -> Result<StartListen, StartListenError> {
        println!("Attempting to listen");
```

enum

```
// Defines the types of messages to expect
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum RequestType {
    RequestWork {
        request_message: String,
        parameter: String,
        sender_timestamp: String,
    },
    CloseConnection {
        initial_timestamp: String,
        final_timestamp: String,
    },
    Invalid(String),
}


// The Implementation for the RequestType Enum
impl RequestType{
    fn from_message_string(message_string: &str, pool: Arc<Pool>) -> RequestType {
        println!("Checking request type...");
```

I can define methods using enums, which is most similar to what I assume is a class. In what scenario would you use a struct?

Comment: A struct is essentially just convenient shorthand for a single-variant enum.

Comment: Both of those comments are completely useless for beginners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A struct is similar to a JavaScript object, except that it has a fixed set of fields and each field has a type. In order to construct an instance of the struct, you must provide ***all*** fields. Your `StartListen` struct has two fields, and you need a `SocketAddr` *and* a `TcpListener` to construct it.

An enum doesn't have an analogy in JavaScript. Instead of having fields, an enum has *variants*. In order to construct an instance of an enum, you must provide ***exactly one*** variant. The variant itself might require data, like a struct, and all fields of the variant must be provided to construct it. Your `RequestType` enum has three variants, and an instance of `RequestType` must be one of `RequestWork`, `CloseConnection` or `Invalid`.

- You can think of a struct as an *aggregate* of things.
- You can think of an enum as a *choice* from a selection of mutually exclusive alternatives. These alternatives may carry data too.